# List mapping in Webflux: map() + stream() vs. flatMapMany() + map() + collectList()

Tags: java, list, spring-webflux, project-reactor

When working with `List`s in Webflux, there are multiple ways how to iterate over nested lists.
Let's say we have a class `Customer`:

```java
public class Customer {
    public String name;
    public List<Order> orders;
}
```

and now want to do some filtering on the `orders`.

##### Mapping/Filtering inside a `map()` using java streams:

```java
Mono<List<Order>> customer = Mono.just(myCustomer)
    .map(customer -> customer.getOrders())
    .map(orders -> orders.stream()
        .filter(order -> order.getStatus().equals("Open"))
        .toList());
```

##### Doing mapping/filtering on the stream level

```java
Mono<List<Order>> customer = Mono.just(myCustomer)
    .flatMapMany(customer -> Flux.fromIterable(customer.getOrders())
    .filter(order -> order.getStatus().equals("Open"))
    .collectList()
```

Note that usually `Mono.just(myCustomer)` will be some `customerService.getCustomer()` network call that returns `Mono<Customer>`.

Now the question: Is one approach better than the other (stylistically, performance-wise,...), or is it a matter of preference?

Comment: In this case (and whenever the 'orders' are coming all at once) they should be the same. Though, if `getOrders()` would be implemented differently and it would return a `Flux<Orders>` you can use the 2nd approach to process/filter elements as they come, one by one.

Comment: Thanks @TrandafirEmanuel! I thought there may be more nuance to the problem.

Comment: Combination of `Flux.fromIterable` & `collectList` looks like NOP here because there are no async calls involved. We are transforming list into `Flux` and then back to list. Most probably it will consume more resources.